# firebase rules and validation

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to do some basic validation on my firebase database to ensure when an order is submitted that both email and mobile are present.

This is the rule I thought who achieve this but I am getting an error in the simulator say write access denied

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Orders": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      "$order_id": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['email', 'phone'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the child node of /Orders

```
"-KeDyBIqnzNik0vOCEfQ" : {
    "date" : "2017-03-02T23:22:32+1100",
    "email" : "beanindustries@gmail.bean",
    "items" : [ {
      "description" : "Almond",
      "name" : "Cappuccino",
      "price" : ".5",
      "qty" : 1
    }, {
      "description" : "Almond",
      "name" : "Cappuccino",
      "price" : ".5",
      "qty" : 1
    } ],
    "name" : "Mr Bean",
    "notes" : "\n\n",
    "phone" : "0412258499",
    "status" : "new"
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the simulator that has the existing data, the path you're writing to, and the data you're writing.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen screen shots added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I wasnt using data section within the simulator which is why my validations failed. I have since pasted the above JSON into that box and the validations appear to be working as expected

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem Paul. And thanks for the self-answer!